# Require, request and requisition

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

According to their dictionary definitions the principal meaning (as verbs) would be to ask, to demand.

To requisition is a little bit more complicated (may take an infinitive) which is why I think, it is more likely to be used as a noun next to “make” i.e. “to make a requisition”.

As for the verbs to require and to request they seem to be closer and can be used to ask and demand something as follows:

> I require a new car.
>
> I request for a new car.

Which would be the nuance differences between them regarding the colloquial, formal or polite usage?

As a noun I know and can understand the differences:

A product request refers to its demand on the market while the product requirements refer to the conditions that the product must comply with.

Comment: *I request **for** a new car* is better I guess. Because you *request someone* but you *request for something.*

Comment: Undoubtedly, *request* is more polite to ask for the *requirement!* -- I *request* for a new car because I (deadly) *require* it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different. Firstly, let's see all three verbs in concern.

The verb *requisition* is used more for official purpose.

> [requisition](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/REQUISITION) - Make a formal request for official services and also meaning #2

An example from OALD for this - *The school was requisitioned as a military hospital.*

The verb *require* has several meanings but in the sense you are guessing, it means *[request and expect](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=require) (#2)*

An example from WW for this - *We require our secretary to be on time*

The verb *request* is to politely express that you need something

> [request](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/request?q=request) - Politely or formally ask for

An example from OxfordDictionaries for this - *the chairman requested that the reports be considered*

**Now your examples:**

> I require a new car **over** I request for a new car

Obviously, the latter sentence is more polite as it includes the word *request*.

Is there any difference in these both -- **yes, there is.**

The former one is just a statement that shows your requirement. On the other hand, the latter one shows you are politely asking for that requirement. To be a bit straightforward, *I require a new car* is ordering someone **over** *I request for a new car* is asking for a favor and doing so, that someone may oblige you by getting you a new car and not old! :)